# How to know that same app is install in another device or not via bluetooth

Tags: android, database, android-bluetooth

I have one Bluetooth application. If I install that app in 2-3 devices then 
 How to know that same app is install in another devices or not like xender.

 How to share local database of application via Bluetooth.?

Comment: What you have done ?

Comment: I can search for device but all device list is showing, I just display same app device list.

Comment: In your app, you have to call a service that will always be in running mode using direct wifi or bluetooth. so whenever another person using your app will scan, it will show the same app user not all bluetooth users. Same functionality is used by many apps like "ShareIt" and other like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can Create UUID's for your Application and connect your application using that UUID. 
While discovering devices, you can check whether the UUID of your application is supported by the other device. If yes, then you can display it, otherwise don't display !!
Something like this to initiate connection - `device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(YOUR_UUID);`

For more insights, refer the BluetoothChat Application by Google, available at https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html